# Python: Is there any way to sort keys in a dictionary with 2 values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

> Python 3.11

I was coding a leaderboard and I haven't found a way, how to sort the users,
my dictionary is this:

```py
users = {
   "level": {
      "Mark": 4,
      "Steve": 3,
      "Justin": 4,
      "Markus": 2
   }, "xp": {
      "Mark": 43,
      "Steve": 25,
      "Justin": 48,
      "Markus": 32
   }
}
```

Is there a way to sort the users first by the level, and then if some users have the same level *(in that case Mark and Justin)*, then sort them again by their xp? So it would be like this:

```
leaderboard = [
   "Justin",
   "Mark",
   "Steve",
   "Markus"
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `sorted(users['level'], key=lambda n: (users['level'][n], users['xp'][n]), reverse=True)`

Comment: try this solution -

>>> users = {
   "level": {
      "Mark": 4,
      "Steve": 3,
      "Justin": 4,
      "Markus": 2
   }, "xp": {
      "Mark": 43,
      "Steve": 25,
      "Justin": 48,
      "Markus": 32
   }
}
>>> leaderboard = sorted(users["level"], key=lambda item: (users['level'][item], users['xp'][item]), reverse=True)
>>> leaderboard
['Justin', 'Mark', 'Steve', 'Markus']

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit:
This answer only is valid if the stability of the sort is ensured. This is true [since Python 2.2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/). Please keep this in mind.
For something more generic and an overall better solution, refer to [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s comment.

This code should achieve your goal:

```py
users = {
    "level": {
        "Mark": 4,
        "Steve": 3,
        "Justin": 4,
        "Markus": 2
    },
    "xp": {
        "Mark": 43,
        "Steve": 25,
        "Justin": 48,
        "Markus": 32
    }
}

leaderboard = [user for user in users["level"]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    leaderboard = sorted(leaderboard, key=lambda user: users["xp"][user], reverse=True)
    leaderboard = sorted(leaderboard, key=lambda user: users["level"][user], reverse=True)
    print(leaderboard)
```

This outputs `['Justin', 'Mark', 'Steve', 'Markus']`

What you described is sorting on level as a primary sort and xp as a secondary sort. As a general rule, you'll want to sort following the lowest level of importance first, and make your way up from there.
Here I first sorted with the `xp` as key, then with the `level`.

Comment: This relies on some guarantees about stable sorting. While this may actually work, it's not *generally* reliable (e.g. on older versions of Python). This can and should be done in *one* sorting pass, not two consecutive sorts.

Comment: You're right, it seems this stability is only guaranteed [since Python 2.2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/). Thanks for pointing it out!